# Problems with proof of Krull's height theorem

Tags: ring-theory, ideals

I want to understand  the proof of next

> **Theorem.** Let $A$ a Noetherian ring and $\mathfrak a=(a_1,...,a_n)$ a proper ideal of $A$. Let $\mathfrak p\in\mathrm{Spec}(A)$ a minimal ideal over $\mathfrak a$. Then $\operatorname {ht}(\mathfrak p) \leq n$.

I don't understand the affirmation: because $\mathfrak p A_{\mathfrak p}$ is minimal over $\mathfrak aA_{\mathfrak p}$ is enough to prove that if $A$ is a Noetherian local ring with maximal ideal $\mathfrak m$, $\mathfrak a=(a_1,...,a_n)$  and $\mathfrak m=\sqrt{\mathfrak a}$ then $\operatorname {ht}\mathfrak m \leq n$. Can you help me? Thank you!

Comment: You should probably edit the title to something more specific

Answer (score 2):

`Do you know these facts?`

- $A_p$ is local ring with $p A_p$, maximal.
- $aA_p$ is an ideal of $A_p$ which can be generated by $n$ elements.
- $p A_p$ is minimal over $aA_p$.
- $\operatorname {ht} pA_p= \operatorname {ht} p.$
- In a local ring $(R,m)$, if $m$ is minimal over an ideal $J$, then $\sqrt J = m$.

---

Now in order to prove that $\operatorname {ht} p \leq n$ one can prove $\operatorname {ht} pA_p \leq n.$ But $p A_p$ is the maximal ideal of local ring $A_p$ and is minimal over an ideal generated with $n$ elements. So it is enough to show that $\operatorname {ht} \leq n$ under the additional hypotheses that the ring is local with $p$ maximal.